# how to vlookup an item in column D and get the value of column a in vba userform?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, userform

i wrote this code but it gives me #N/A.

```
Dim item

item=Application.VLookup(CB1.Value,Worksheets("Shete1").Range("D1").CurrentRegion, 1, False)
```

Column D is the item name and column a is its number and i want to have item number be stored in item.

Comment: for `VLOOKUP` the term looked up for must be in 1st column of the lookup table ... value returned hence must be right of looked up value.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but is there any other ways to find an item name in the whole sheet and then reaching the value of first column of the related row, except changing columns.

Comment: `but is there any other ways to find an item name in the whole sheet` Yup :) [.FIND](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combination of index and match to return the value you are looking for.

Example:

```
item = Application.Index(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"),Application.Match(CB1.Value,Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1"),False))
```

Note that "D1" will only search the first cell of column D.  If you want to search the whole column then swap out "D1" with "D:D".

Comment: it perfectly works in the usrform command button click sub but as it needs to be repeated for the  other command click in the same userform, i make a sub in the module and put the code there but it gives me a run time error object needed. what do i need to change?